# changing number of ordered samples with replacement to unordered samples with replacement

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Suppose you have a bag of groceries with $M$ distinct items. The items
> are either produce, animal products, toiletries, or grains. Consider a
> random draw from the bag of $D$ items and lay them all out in an
> (ordered) row. Let $N_r$ be the number of possible outcomes with
> replacement, $N_p$ be the number of possible outcomes without
> replacement, and $N_c$ be the number of possible categorical outcomes
> with replacement (i.e., produce - toiletries - grain - grain - ...).
> Assume there are at least $D$ items of each category.
>
> a) List $N_r$, $N_c$, and $N_p$ from smallest to largest.

$N_r = M^{D}$

$N_p = \frac{M!}{(M-D)!}$

$N_c=4^D$

$N_c < N_p < N_r$

> b) Calculate and order similar expressions for unordered collections.

My original answer was this:

$N_r = \frac{M^{D}}{D!}$

$N_p = \frac{M!}{(M-D)!}*\frac{1}{D!}$

$N_c=\frac{4^D}{D!}$

$N_c < N_p < N_r$

But now I'm thinking I made a mistake for $N_r$ since a formula I found online for unordered samples with replacement was $${n+k-1}\choose{k}$$

So in my case it would be $${{M+D-1}\choose{D}} =\frac{(M+D-1)!}{D!(M-1)!}$$

But I'm also thinking that this formula doesn't apply since in the question we are considering categories instead of individual objects. So I'm not really sure which idea I need to go with.

Comment: You do indeed have an error.  Notice for example that $\dfrac{4^D}{D!}$ has only prime factors of $2$ in the numerator while it has at least one factor of $3$ in the denominator (*assuming $D\geq 3$*) and so is not even an integer and so could not possibly be an answer to a counting problem.

Comment: The punchline will be that for part (b) where you consider unordered selections, you will be using the stars-and-bars formula you found.  In the first case with $M$ as itself, in the second case using $4$ in its place.  The formula *does* apply.  Since you tagged this with [Probability] as well, be warned that the outcomes counted by stars-and-bars are *not* equally likely to occur in nearly every scenario you might encounter them and that formula should *not* occur in a denominator.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry I am getting confused, are you saying that my answer for unordered $N_r$ is correct but my answer for unordered $N_c$ is incorrect?

Comment: I am saying that your answer for $N_r$ when unordered is incorrect *and* your answer for $N_c$ when unordered is incorrect.  The correct answers for both will both use the stars-and-bars formula you found, those being $\binom{D+M-1}{M-1}$ and $\binom{D+4-1}{4-1}$ respectively (*or rearranged as you have as $\binom{M+D-1}{D}$ and $\binom{4+D-1}{D}$ if you prefer*)

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. But I'm just confused as to why the answer for $N_r$ is incorrect since we are considering the categories themselves instead of the individual items in the categories

Comment: For the individual items rather than the categories... well... that is the same as just having *many more* categories which are just *very specific*.  What was the grains category is now the rice category, the bread category, the cake category, the waffle category, etc...

Comment: Also, again, you have $\dfrac{M^D}{D!}$ is not going to be an integer for most values of $M$ and $D$ and so couldn't possibly be the answer to a counting question.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh I see what you're saying, thank you so much for clarifying! my other answers seem correct  though right?

Comment: @JMoravitz hi sorry just one more question. Since we have those new values for unordered $N_r$ and unordered $N_c$, does that change which ones are smallest and largest? i.e.: is it still true that $N_c < N_p < N_r$